# use bash to open a file and output the last line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get only the last command ran in a different Bash window.  I have the other Bash window's PID.  I can run

`APID=<bash pid number>; gdb -batch --eval "attach $APID" --eval "call write_history(\"/tmp/bash_history-$APID.txt\")" --eval 'detach' --eval 'q'`

but it writes that to a file.

What would be an `sh` command that would output the last line of the result of that function call without creating a temporary file?

Comment: man tail is your friend.

Comment: @funkodebat `tail -1 ~/.bash_history`

Comment: @alexus: `.bash_history` is usually only written when the shell exits so a simple `tail` probably won't work.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You most likely right, but that's what OP asked for.

Comment: @alexus: I dont think so. It looks like he's asking `gdb` to tell Bash to write the history, which is contained in memory, of a currently running shell. In fact, I just tested it, and that's what it does. And `tail -n 1 ~/.bash_history` doesn't show the most recent command from the test session.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I guess he's question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (it would not create a temporary file and will print the last line):

```
APID=<bash pid number> gdb -batch --eval "attach $APID" --eval "call write_history(\"/dev/stdout\")" --eval 'detach' --eval 'q' | tail -1
```

Comment: `/dev/stdout` works for me, but note that it outputs to the terminal being inspected. If you want it to output to another terminal, perhaps the one running the `gdb` command, use the specific terminal device instead of `/dev/stdout` (e.g. `/dev/pts/15`).